# Integrated terminal: update environment variable

Tags: macos, go, visual-studio-code, beego

This is my first day using vscode with beego. 
I used IntelliJ otherwise, which has a setting to specify custom paths for GOPATH.

Vscode does not seem to have this option of allowing multiple GOPATHs, and I thought I could try to append `GOPATH` variable for all integrated terminal sessions.

I've added following to `settings.json`

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "GOPATH": "/Users/hk/go:/Users/hk/Documents/code/go/go-beego"
}
```

However, it has no effect on `tasks.json`

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "go: run beego",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo \"gopath is $GOPATH\" | bee run portal"
    }
]
}
```

Output of tasks

```
gopath is /Users/hk/go
FATAL    ▶ 0001 No application 'portal'
found in your GOPATH. 
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 255
```

EDIT: The integrated terminal does not honour the following:
`"go.gopath": "/Users/hk/go:/Users/hk/Documents/code/go/go-beego",`

Comment: Are you using the vscode-go extension?  You can set the path in ways other than the environment variable, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension

Comment: I've tried `go.gopath` also, terminal does not honor that. I do `go get` and see gopath is set to default.

Comment: Or if I could get to see the built in `go install` command, which works, I can reverse it to run my command.